# Should I use nofollow at register and login pages?

Tags: seo, anchor, nofollow

On my site, I have a register and login page which are frequently indexed by Google as I can see it on the Webmanager Tools page. That's disturbing, because I want the users to find other keywords and not the login or register page and/or text. My question is simple: should I use the nofollow attribute to my anchors at the header and footer of my page?

If not, why not?

Comment: Just because it's indexed doesn't mean it's going to rank well and/or outrank your other pages. If they do then your website has other really big problems. I wouldn't be thinking about this for another second.

Comment: That makes it clear, hehe. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To stop them being indexed use the robots meta tag with a noindex.

Nofollow on links to it will help the spiders avoid those pages but will not stop them indexing them if they ever get there.

Comment: Hmm, that's a much better answer. Thanks, can't think why I forget this.